# How to track PAGEVIEW event with parameter

Tags: google-analytics

I am tracking page view events in GA4. In my case the event fire when the visitor open the page.
Suppose the the page is product details page, I need to send the ID of the current product as parameter with the event
What I need to do is to create custom audience from visitors who viewed certain pages filtered by product ID.
How to achieve this?

I tried the page view event but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably send over the ID as an event parameter on the page_view event. I don't know if you are leveraging GTM or not on your site but you can create a variable that pulls the ID from the page and dump it as a custom parameter.